# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in function

Tags: javascript, jinja2

Any help will be appreciated.

```
 <button type="button" 
       id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary"
       data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
       onclick="notify({"IP": "0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255", "app_code": "", "custodian_email": "", "custodian_id": "", "custodian_name": ""})">
     <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane" style="margin-right:5px"></i>
        Notify
    </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using double quotes to delimit the `onclick` attribute value, and also to delimit the strings inside the attribute. That can't be parsed, because the double quote before `IP` ends the attribute. Use single quotes for one of them instead.

```
<button type="button" 
   id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary"
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
   onclick='notify({"IP": "0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255", "app_code": "", "custodian_email": "", "custodian_id": "", "custodian_name": ""})'>
 <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane" style="margin-right:5px"></i>
    Notify
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using " as closing and opening tag in the inner dict and in the function, just change

`notify({"IP": "0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255", "app_code": "", "custodian_email": "", "custodian_id": "", "custodian_name": ""}`

to:
`notify({'IP': '0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255', 'app_code': '...'})`